# Asyncronous calls in Loop not working as expected

Tags: client-object-model

I need to iterate through site's doc libraries, their content types and their fields and display the results. When looping through the doc libraries, in the success call back, I am always getting the last doc library. how can I resolve this ?

Comment: code? without it we dont know where your going wrong ;) !

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative using the following approach

```
var excludedLibraries = ["List Template Gallery", "Test"];
var clientContext;
var docLibNames = [];
var docLibCounter = 0;
var contentTypeNames = [];
var contentTypeCounter = 0;
var field = {displayName: '', staticName: '', type: '', readOnly: '', hidden: ''};
var contentType = {name: '', id: '', readOnly: '', fields: []};
var docLib = {name: '', contentTypes: []};
var docLibs = [];
var docLibColl;
var cntTypeColl;
var fields;

function getdocLibs() {
    var siteUrl = 'RelativeSiteURl';
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    docLibColl = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
    clientContext.load(docLibColl, 'Include(Title, BaseType, ContentTypes)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onDocLibQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onDocLibQuerySucceeded() {
    var listEnumerator =  docLibColl.getEnumerator();
    while(listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var list = listEnumerator.get_current();
        if(list.get_baseType() == 1){
            var docLibName = list.get_title();
            if($.inArray(docLibName, excludedLibraries) == -1)
                docLibNames.push(docLibName);               
        }
    }
    getContentTypes();
}

function getContentTypes()
{
    if(docLibCounter < docLibNames.length) {            
        var list = docLibColl.getByTitle(docLibNames[docLibCounter]);
        cntTypeColl = list.get_contentTypes();
        clientContext.load(cntTypeColl, 'Include(Name, Id, ReadOnly, Fields)'); 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCntTypeQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }   
    else
    {
        var firstUl = $('<ul>');
        $('#DisplayData').append(firstUl);
        for(var  i = 0; i < docLibs.length; i++) {
            var firstLi = $('<li>');
            firstUl.append(firstLi.text('Document Library Name: ' + docLibs[i].name));
            for(var j = 0; j < docLibs[i].contentTypes.length; j++) {
                var secondUl = $('<ul>');
                firstLi.append(secondUl);
                var secondLi = $('<li>');
                secondUl.append(secondLi.text('Content Type Name: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].name));
                var thirdUl = $('<ul>');
                secondLi.append(thirdUl);
                var thirdLi = $('<li>');
                thirdUl.append(thirdLi.text('Properties'));
                var fourthUl = $('<ul>');
                thirdLi.append(fourthUl);
                var fourthLi = $('<li>');
                fourthUl.append(fourthLi.text('Id: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].id));
                var fifthLi = $('<li>');
                fourthUl.append(fifthLi.text('Read Only: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].readOnly));

                for(var k = 0; k < docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].fields.length; k++) {
                    var thirdUl = $('<ul>');
                    secondLi.append(thirdUl);
                    var thirdLi = $('<li>');
                    thirdUl.append(thirdLi.text('Field Name: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].fields[k].displayName));
                    var fourthUl = $('<ul>');
                    thirdLi.append(fourthUl);
                    var fourthLi = $('<li>');
                    fourthUl.append(fourthLi.text('Static Name: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].fields[k].staticName));
                    var fifthLi = $('<li>');
                    fourthUl.append(fifthLi.text('Type: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].fields[k].type));
                    var sixthLi = $('<li>');
                    fourthUl.append(sixthLi.text('Read Only: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].fields[k].readOnly));
                    var seventhLi = $('<li>');
                    fourthUl.append(seventhLi.text('Hidden: ' + docLibs[i].contentTypes[j].fields[k].hidden));

                }
            }
        }
        $('#Status').text('Data fetching complete.');
    }   
}

function onCntTypeQuerySucceeded() {
    var cntTypeEnumerator =  cntTypeColl.getEnumerator();
    contentTypeNames = [];
    contentTypeCounter = 0;
    while(cntTypeEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var cntType = cntTypeEnumerator.get_current();
        var cntTypeName = cntType.get_name();
        contentTypeNames.push(cntTypeName);
        }
    getFields();
}

function getFields()
{
    if(contentTypeCounter < contentTypeNames.length)
    {
        var cntType = cntTypeColl.getItemAtIndex(contentTypeCounter);
        var cntTypeName = cntType.get_name();
        var cntTypeId = cntType.get_id().toString();    
        var cntTypeReadOnly = cntType.get_readOnly();
        contentType = {name: cntTypeName, id: cntTypeId, readOnly: cntTypeReadOnly, fields: []};

        fields = cntType.get_fields();
        clientContext.load(fields, 'Include(Title, StaticName, FieldTypeKind, ReadOnlyField, Hidden)');         
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFieldsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));     
    }
    else
    {
        docLib.name = docLibNames[docLibCounter]
        docLibs.push(jQuery.extend(true, {}, docLib));
        docLib = {name: '', contentTypes: []};
        docLibCounter++;
        $('#Percent').text(Math.round(100*docLibCounter/docLibNames.length));
        getContentTypes();
    }
}

function onFieldsQuerySucceeded() {
    var fieldEnumerator = fields.getEnumerator();
    while(fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var field = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        var fieldDisplayName = field.get_title();
        var fieldStaticName = field.get_staticName();
        var fieldType = field.get_fieldTypeKind();
        var fieldReadOnly = field.get_readOnlyField();
        var fieldHidden = field.get_hidden();
        var field = {displayName: fieldDisplayName, staticName: fieldStaticName, type: fieldType, readOnly: fieldReadOnly, hidden: fieldHidden};
        contentType.fields.push(field);
    }
    docLib.contentTypes.push(jQuery.extend(true, {}, contentType));
    contentType = {name: '', id: '', readOnly: '', fields: []};
    contentTypeCounter++;
    getFields();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request Failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getdocLibs, "sp.js");
});
```